# Net 4 security settings for signed assemblies

Tags: c#, security, .net-4.0

I have an application that has been working fine until now using strong name assemblies under Net 3.5.

Recently I have moved the project to Net 4.0, and I have also signed the assemblies with a code signing certificate. When I start the app on a machine that has Windows 7 installed, the program will not start (it throws an exception before executing the first line of code).

To try and fine out what the problem was I installed the program, still using Net 4.0, but without signing the assemblies with the code signing certificate; and the program works okay.

So, my question is: Under Net 4, how can I grant FullTrust to assemblies that have been signed with our Code Signing Certificate?

Thanks,
Martin.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to determine what happened without the exception or other details but security changed significantly in .Net 4.0. The simplest way to revert back to the pre-4.0 settings is to include the following attribute:

```
[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]
```

See [Security Transparent Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191569.aspx) for more detail.